# Does Wix3.5 support in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, wix, wix3.5

I tried installing WiX 3.5 but my old wix project developed using WiX does not open in VS2010.

Is there any specific settings I need to handle?

Comment: [WiX 3.5](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2011/1/31/wix-v3.5-released) adds official support of VS 2010. [WiX 3.6](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2012/9/3/wix-v3.6-released) does the same for VS 2012.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite a matrix:

- [WiX v3.5](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2011/1/31/wix-v3.5-released/) supports `VS2005`, `VS2008`, `VS2010`.
- [WiX v3.6](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2012/9/3/wix-v3.6-released/) supports `VS2008`, `VS2010`, `VS2012`.
- [WiX v3.7](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2012/12/24/wix-v3.7-released/) supports `VS2008`, `VS2010`, `VS2012`.
- [WiX v3.8](http://www.joyofsetup.com/2013/10/14/visual-studio-2013-support-for-wix-available/) supports `VS2008`, `VS2010`, `VS2012`, `VS2013`.
- WiX v4.0 will support `VS2010`, `VS2012`, `VS2013`.

However, you might consider upgrading to WiX v3.7 since it is newest and compatible with WiX v3.5.

Comment: So as per the above info i can't use WIX v3.7 with VS2013